# Was Kabir a Hindu or Muslim?

Tags: comparative-religions

Kabir Das was a great saint who wrote both in favor of Hindus and Muslims. Was Kabir himself a Hindu or a Muslim ?

(Kabir Das (IAST: Kabīr[1]) was a 15th-century Indian mystic poet and saint, whose writings influenced Hinduism's Bhakti movement and his verses are found in Sikhism's scripture Guru Granth Sahib.[2][3][4] His early life was in a Muslim family, but he was strongly influenced by his teacher, the Hindu bhakti leader Ramananda.[2] Kabir was born in the Indian city of Varanasi. )

Comment: write something about Kabir Das, Who is he ?  also I think it's off topic ...you can read about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabir)

Comment: It's off topic, ok

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Hinduism.SE

Answer (score 1):

Lorenzen in his review of Kabir's philosophy and poetry writes, "the extent to which Kabir borrowed elements from Islam is controversial. Many recent scholars have argued that he simply **rejected Islam and took almost all his ideas and beliefs from the Hindu tradition**.

His might answer your question.

Comment: I beg to disagree. Kabir was very much a supporter of Muslim values and Hindu values.  My question was given the fact above , would you call Kabir a Hindu or Muslim ?

Comment: @SacrificialEquation  In the wiki it is not very clear. Some time it say he was a Muslims and some times it say he was not a Muslim

Comment: @SacrificialEquation _(from kabir das biography )_, In this situation Islam disallow that you cannot say he was Muslim or non Muslim.. if you are looking for the answer  according to  others religion , better withdraw the  question and ask on others network.. also you can read I write about something according to the islam

Answer (score 0):

**Note** This is not answer, I write this post for awareness and keep away to misleading and misunderstanding...

**if anyone read Islamic history,**

**Example as a:** You will find many people (non Muslim) accept Islam before dying (2 days ago), Even accept Islam before took the  last breath in Jihad  or others situation.

**Question is** : was kabir das muslim or hindu ?

**Answer** will be Yes or no

But (**from kabir das biography** ) In this situation Islam disallow that you cannot say he was Muslim or non Muslim,
Because if anyone die as a Muslim he was Muslim, Otherwise he was non Muslim (Kafir).
It's better we could say Allah know the secret

**Innallaha alimun khabir:**  Indeed Allah is all-knowing, all-aware.

**From Quran**

**Sura** al-Hujurat - الحُجُرَاتِ

**Ayats** 12,13

يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ ٱجۡتَنِبُواْ كَثِيرٗا مِّنَ ٱلظَّنِّ إِنَّ بَعۡضَ ٱلظَّنِّ إِثۡمٞۖ وَلَا تَجَسَّسُواْ وَلَا يَغۡتَب بَّعۡضُكُم بَعۡضًاۚ أَيُحِبُّ أَحَدُكُمۡ أَن يَأۡكُلَ لَحۡمَ أَخِيهِ مَيۡتٗا فَكَرِهۡتُمُوهُۚ وَٱتَّقُواْ ٱللَّهَۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ تَوَّابٞ رَّحِيمٞ

O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would detest it. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance and Merciful.

يَـٰٓأَيُّهَا ٱلنَّاسُ إِنَّا خَلَقۡنَٰكُم مِّن ذَكَرٖ وَأُنثَىٰ وَجَعَلۡنَٰكُمۡ شُعُوبٗا وَقَبَآئِلَ لِتَعَارَفُوٓاْۚ إِنَّ أَكۡرَمَكُمۡ عِندَ ٱللَّهِ أَتۡقَىٰكُمۡۚ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ عَلِيمٌ خَبِيرٞ

O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted.